# С помощью python загрузить в поисковик все строки excel

Tags: python, excel

У меня есть excel файл с 1000 строками, в каждой набор символов из 10 символов.
Мне нужно каждый из них вставить поочередно в поиск, например, яндекса.
Если выдаваемых результатов более одного - как то отметить эту строку, которую поисковик нашел. (потом я уже в ручную поиск повторю с нужной строкой)
По одному результату будет в каждой строке, а я ищу когда 2 и более.

Comment: у вас слишком обширный вопрос. Сфокусируйтесь на том, что у вас вызывает трудности и попробуйте сформулировать вопрос соответственно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно написать функцию, возвращающую число результатов поиска.

Пример:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_search_results_no(search_str):
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com/search',
                     params={'q':f'{search_str}'}
                )
    if not r.ok:
        r.raise_for_status()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    n = re.sub('\D', '', re.sub('[^\d]*\s(\d.*\d)\s[^\d]*', r'\1', 
                                soup.find('div',{'id':'resultStats'}).text))
    if n == '':
        return 0
    return int(n)
```

Использование:

```
In [149]: get_search_results_no('MaxU')
Out[149]: 1050000

In [150]: get_search_results_no('Кирилл Вишняков')
Out[150]: 983000
```

Comment: Спасибо - это количество результатов поиска, но меня интересует "Как вставить в поисковик поочередно каждую строку excel файла"

Comment: @КириллВишняков, я думаю вам стоит задать новый вопрос и постараться в нём максимально точно сформулировать что вам необходимо. Жалательно с примерами...