# Вставить в поисковик поочередно все строки Excel

Tags: python, excel, поиск

У меня есть Excel файл такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Только строк больше тысячи. Один столбец. Необходимо каждую из них проверить в поисковике. Если вариантов выдачи больше одного - отметить эту строку. Используя Python.

Comment: Покажите код, который вы написали решая эту задачу, или идите на фриланс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы воспользовался [модулем Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) в данном случае:

```
import pandas as pd      #  pip install pandas

# read Excel to DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\download\data.xlsx')
```

исходный DataFrame:

```
                      query
0  kjhfkjsdahkjthkrjthkejth
1         "+Python +Pandas"
2         "Кирилл Вишняков"
3  qwekjhbancjmwghkejgfhkjh
```

используем [get_search_results_no()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/863251/211923) для подсчета числа результатов поиска:

```
df['results'] = df['query'].map(get_search_results_no)
```

добавим флаг, удовлетворяющий условию:

```
df['Flag'] = df['results'] > 1
```

результат:

```
In [84]: df
Out[84]:
                      query   results   Flag
0  kjhfkjsdahkjthkrjthkejth         0  False
1         "+Python +Pandas"  10100000   True
2         "Кирилл Вишняков"     18900   True
3  qwekjhbancjmwghkejgfhkjh         0  False
```

сохраняем DataFrame как Excel файл:

```
df.to_excel(r'c:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

Результат (Excel):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]